# how do i toggle disabled between two buttons in react map

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of candidates with two buttons hire and reject. when i press hire it should be disabled and reject stays enabled. When i press reject it should be disabled and hire must be enabled.

```
{result && result.map(appliedCandidate => {
  if (joblist.id === appliedCandidate.jobid) {
  return (
    <div className="row pb-3">
        <div className=" col-md-4 text-left font-weight-bold">
            <p className={this.state.applystatus==="hire" ? "text-  info" : "text-danger"}>
            {appliedCandidate.firstName}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4">
                    <div className="back-btn">
                        <input id='hire' type='button' ref='hire' data-id={appliedCandidate.jobid} name={appliedCandidate.id} data-tag={appliedCandidate.phoneno} onClick={this.hireReject} className="btn btn-success card-btn-width" value='hire' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-4">
                    <div className="back-btn">
                        <input id='reject' type='button' ref='reject' data-id={appliedCandidate.jobid} name={appliedCandidate.id} data-tag={appliedCandidate.phoneno} onClick={this.hireReject} className="btn btn-danger card-btn-width" value='reject' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-4">
                    <div className="back-btn">
                        <Link to={{ pathname: '/individualchat', state: { name: appliedCandidate.firstName, jobid: appliedCandidate.jobid, id: appliedCandidate.id, Title: appliedCandidate.Title } }}>
                          <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">chat</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>)
  }
})}

hireReject = (event) => {

  var dis = event.target.setAttribute('disabled','true')

  const phoneno = event.target.getAttribute('data-tag');
  const id = event.target.getAttribute('name');
  const jobid = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  const applystatus = event.target.value;
  { applystatus === 'hire' ? toastr.success('Successfully hired') : toastr.error('Successfully rejected') }
        { applystatus === 'hire' ? document.getElementById('reject').disabled = false : document.getElementById('hire').disabled = false }
        this.setState({
            jobid: jobid, id: id, candidatephoneno: phoneno, applystatus: applystatus
        }, () => {
            this.props.hireReject(this.state)

        })
        {return applystatus === 'hire' ? 'hired' : 'rejected'}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider separating the buttons and hiring/rejecting logic into its own component like the following so you can better handle the toggling.

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Candidate from "./Candidate";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  render() {
    const candidates = [{ name: "Bob" }, { name: "Sam" }, { name: "Jessie" }];
    return candidates.map(candidate => {
      return <Candidate candidate={candidate} />;
    });
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Candidate.js

```
import React from "react";

class Candidate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hired: null
  };

  handleHire = () => {
    this.setState({
      hired: true
    });
  };

  handleReject = () => {
    this.setState({
      hired: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const hired = this.state.hired;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.candidate.name}</h4>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleHire}
          disabled={hired == null ? false : hired}
        >
          Hire
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleReject}
          disabled={hired == null ? false : !hired}
        >
          Reject
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Candidate;
```

Here is a sandbox for your reference as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrlyq0l29m